# Computer and FTDI cable baud rates

Tags: ftdi, baud

Hi I have and FTDI cable that can run at 2Mbauds. I connected this to a microcontroller that is sending messages at 2Mbaud and connect the usb port end to my computer. I have pyserial read the incoming messages with a baud rate of 2Mbaud from the COM port, but I'm a little confused on how it is able to read it. I've heard is that computers can max have a baud rate of 230400 baud so how is it correctly reading the 2Mbaud from the FTDI cable?

Additionally, when I go into my device manager and look at the port settings of my FTDI cable, the highest selectable baud is 921600 while my other com ports are 128000. So I'm also a little confused on what the max baud rate of my computer is. Is there a place in the settings of my computer that I can find this answer or do I have to run my own test somehow?

Comment: baud rate is set between the serial device and the  FTDI chip ... the connection  between the FTDI chip and your computer is USB

Comment: "* I've heard is that computers can max have a baud rate of 230400 baud*" -- where? Without a citation, we have no way to evaluate the veracity of this statement.

Answer (score 2):

You have a cable with USB to serial converter. That is not a PC any more but only a chip that works within the capabilities it has.

Depending on which exact cable and chip you have, it might be a 12 MBps USB chip and capable of up to 3 Mbps baud rate, or it might be a 480 Mbps USB chip capable of 12 Mbps baud rate.

And no, PCs are not limited to baud rate of 230400. Their built-in serial ports or USB serial ports might not be capable of working faster because it is outside of RS-232 interface specs, so it does not make sense to communicate at 12 MBps using RS-232 level converter because the level converters limit the speed to 230400 rate. The 230400 is just convenient multiple of 115200 rate, a typical maximum for built-in UARTs.

So to be more exact, if using RS-232, the slew rate of 30V per microsecond and the signal allowed to be 4% of the bit time in the 6V transition region means the bit rate limit is 200kbps. However, that is just one way to calculate it, and by violating the RS-232 specs in many ways, 1 Mbaud capable RS-232 PHYs exist.

Your Windows computer isn't the limitation, something else is, like the UART chip or the physical interface chip for RS-232 or RS-485.

Also the program you use to access the serial port may be a limitation itself if it does not expect high data rates, and there may be other issues like buffering in the UART chips.

For example I have used my FTDI cable at the fastest possible rate of 3 Mbps for years, but the trick is that it can transmit and receive bytes out at 3 MBps, but because USB uses 1ms polling period and the chip has 256 byte buffer, it can receive only 256 bytes in every 1ms, limiting the throughput to average 256000 bytes per second instead of being capable of throughput of 300000 bytes per second. So it can transfer at 3 Mbaud but only bursts of 256 bytes per 1ms, depending on computer, and other non-idealites, likely slightly less.

I have also lately used another FTDI chip capable of 12 Mbps baud rate, and it has also worked with generic terminal programs just fine. It boasts 30 MB/sec rate if UART is not used. It has 2 kilobyte buffer, able to transfer 2048 bytes in 1ms, which means it really can transfer data continuously to PC at 12 Mbps.

Answer (score 2):

> I've heard is that computers can max have a baud rate of 230400 baud

No. Certain very popular chips from the 1980s had a maximum baud rate of 115200 when clocked by a 1.8432MHz clock (which was standard, at the time, for historical reasons that extend back to the 1960s). Some later clones of those chips, and some other UART devices, supported 2x and 4x that rate (230400 and 460800) — although such support was never terribly common in the heyday of the PC serial port.

"Computers" in general have no such restriction, and USB currently runs anywhere between 1.5Mbit/s (6.5 times as fast as 230400), and 80Gbit/s (almost 350,000 times as fast).

Comment: "Certain very popular chip" almost certainly is the 16550A UART (which replaced the 16550, 16450, and 8250)  The even more modern 16550C can support 930kbps and 16550D can support up to 3Mbps (but these never had a chance at market share since USB was already available)

Comment: @BenVoigt Sure, but if computers needed to be backward compatible, amd even if 16550D could support 24 MHz clock input, you had to use 1.8432 MHz clock to be software compatible, being limited to 115.2 kbps. Integrated chipsets had switchable clocks, but without suppory (DOS program, Windows drivers) for the specific chipset, you are limited to 115.2 kbps. And 16550D datasheet says max 1.5Mbaud, not 3.

Comment: @Justme: There are three lists of high baud rates, and it's actually the middle supply voltage that reaches 3Mbps.   https://www.ti.com/product/TL16C550D

Answer (score 0):

Baud rates are restricted by digital rise times (think square wave, after a while inductance filters square waves to something that looks more like a triangle or sine wave because it reduces frequency content/bandwidth of the signal). So the cable and length can affect performance along with protocol and voltage levels :

This is for RS485
[image]
Source: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla049b/snla049b.pdf
This is for RS232
[image]
Source: https://tom.ji42.com/?p=26082

It is also dependent on digital noise, the higher the baud rate, the more susceptible it is to noise and you'll see more errors in your message.

Comment: The table from the website may be practical but provides no source or data to back those numbers up. It would be hard to find a cable that is within the 2500pF limit at lengths over 40-50 meters, but as usual, anything could be possible by violating the various RS-232 limits for slew rate, current, etc. But I think the question is more about the capabilities of FTDI chips as UARTs, instead of using them for RS-232 or RS-485, as these are commonly used as "TTL" logic levels.